# formatting data inputs for Matlab streamline function

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm attempting to draw streamlines for a two-dimensional vector field. I have the data in a two-dimensional array with one column each containing the X coordinate, y-coordinate, horizontal velocity, and vertical velocity. I'm attempting to use the streamline function but I'm having trouble figuring out how to format the input data correctly.

I know that each input matrix should be the same size. So I have attempted to use the following to get workable inputs:

```
[X Y]= meshgrid(sf(1:250:end,1), sf(1:250:end, 2));
[U V]= meshgrid(sf(1:250:end,3), sf(1:250:end,4));
```

But my velocity matrices obviously no longer make sense compared to my locations.

I'm at a bit of a loss so any help would be awesome.

Comment: where do your `x` `y` come from? how are they generated?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) to re-arrange your data into a regular grid

```
f = min( sf(:,1:2), [], 1 ); %// XY grid starting points
t = max( sf(:,1:2), [], 1 ); %// XY endpoints
[X Y] = meshgrid( linspace( f(1), t(1), 50 ), linspace( f(2), t(2), 50 ) ); %//grid
U = griddata( sf(:,1), sf(:,2), sf(:,3), X, Y );
V = griddata( sf(:,1), sf(:,2), sf(:,4), X, Y );
startx = ; %// define streamline starting points
starty = ; %// 
streamline( X, Y, U, V, startx, starty );
```